# C# Disable default windows contextstrip from within a textbox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, contextmenustrip

I have disabled the default context strip throughout my form, and replaced with my own.
Within my contextmenustrip i have a toolstriptextbox, however when right-clicking within this it brings up the default windows context menu..
Thanks in advance for any and all replies,
Regards,
        **Dave**

Comment: forgot to mention i wish to be rid of this default context menu ^.^

Comment: Please show us the code, how you disabled the contextmenu and set your own. And tag the question wether it concerns WinForms or WPF.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Easiest way to remove the default right-click menu is to define your own (empty) menu:

```
myTextBox.ContextMenuStrip = new ContextMenuStrip();
```

This will, in one line, remove the default Windows right-click options. Understand that the keyboard shortcuts (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd>) will all still work; you're not disabling the basic functionality, just the mouse-able access to it.

For a TextBox within a ContextMenu of another TextBox, it's a little trickier, but basically you can directly access the TextBox that is contained within the ToolStripItem, using the item's TextBox property. This property is a vanilla `System.Windows.Forms.TextBox`, like any other you'd have in your app:

```
myToolStripTextBox.TextBox.ContextMenuStrip = new ContextMenuStrip();
```